# Locally free sheaf - transition functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I try to understand the green isomorphisms in the following diagram:
[image]

Where do they come from?
(E is a locally free sheaf.)

Thank you.

Comment: What are the givens? If $\phi$ is given to be an isomorphism of sheaves already, then the green arrow is just $\phi$ restricted.

Comment: All arrows except the green ones are given. But $\phi$ is a map of modules, not sheaves.

Comment: There is still context missing so I'm going to make some assumptions. Since you said it's locally free, then $U_i$ is probably an open cover on which $E$ is free. Then $\phi$ and $\psi$ are components of the isomorphism of sheaves expressing said freeness.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then the green arrows are just the restriction, as I said in the first comment.

Comment: But what if $E(U_i) \to E(U_i \cap U_j)$ is not surjective? Then there are elements I don't know how to apply $\phi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35831/discussion-between-prospect-and-adiji).

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathscr E$ is a locally free sheaf, you actually get more than what you drew. You get isomorphisms
$$\mathscr E|_{U_i} \stackrel {\phi_i} \longrightarrow \mathcal O_{U_i}^r.$$
Then you can just restrict these to get the required arrows (green in your diagram).

Comment: The issue was already solved in the chat.